# How to apply direction css attribute in list elements

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, arabic, direction

I have some legacy html markup and I need to enable Arabic language support.

So, I have a list of news headlines and render them in `<li>` elements.

Here is sode:

```
..
<li>
<a>some Arabic text</a>
<em>news datetime</em>
</li>
..
```

So, I need to apply rigth text-alignment and direction rtl for anchor, but not for datetime. 
I applied text aligment for `<li>` element and everything is fine.
But I need to apply "direction: rtl" style to anchor and here goes my problem.

I've tried to create `<div>` element with rtl direction attribute and put anchor into it. This works fine in chrome, but I need to support IE6+

Also I've tried to apply direction attribute to `<li>` and override this attr in `<em>`, but this doesn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Vitali.

Comment: I geniuenly feel sorry for you having to support IE6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
li {direction:rtl}
em {direction:ltr; float:left}
```

Comment: `li em {...` would probably be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

**if em is out of li**

```
<ul dir="rtl">
     <li>العربية</li>
     <em>11/24/2011</em>
     <li>العربية</li>
     <em>11/24/2011</em>
     <li>العربية</li>
     <em>11/24/2011</em>
     <li>العربية</li>
     <em>11/24/2011</em>
</ul>
```

**if u need em inside div**

```
<style>
ul { direction:rtl; } ul li em{direction:ltr;} /* em{direction:ltr; float:left;} */
</style>
```

---

```
<ul>
         <li>العربية
         <em>11/24/2011</em>
         </li>
         <li>العربية
         <em>11/24/2011</em>
         </li>
         <li>العربية
         <em>11/24/2011</em>
         </li>
</ul>
```

if your arabic script **contain english words**

```
<style>
    ul { direction:rtl; } ul li{ direction:rtl; } ul li em{direction:ltr;} /* em{direction:ltr; float:left;} */
</style>
```

Comment: @Truth `em` is not `rtl` try it :) , cause date time will show up correctly , if `rtl` effect `em` in this code output is like `2011/24/11` but it's not